# about Docker-Prometheus mysql exporter database

Tags: mysql, docker, prometheus

I'm trying to show data from mysql database on prometheus. But I can't find the query to show the data of my database.
I've used docker and here's how i connected prometheus and mysql exporter.

-prometheus-

```
docker run -d --name prometheus -h prometheus -p 9090:9090 -v C:\Docker\prometheus\prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

-mysql-(* is my ip and the database ip)

```
docker run -d --name mysqld_exporter -p 9104:9104 -e DATA_SOURCE_NAME="***************@(***.***.*.***:****)/prometheus" prom/mysqld-exporter --collect.auto_increment.columns --collect.binlog_size --collect.engine_innodb_status --collect.engine_tokudb_status --collect.global_status --collect.global_variables --collect.info_schema.tables
```

-prometheus.yml-

```
- job_name : 'mysql'
static_configs:
- targets: ['***.**.***.*:9104']
- job_name : 'prometheus'
static_configs:
- targets: ['***.**.***.*:9104']
```

-database-

name : prometheus

table : covid_19

Columns : num, temperature

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27PbX.png)

so the point is that i want to show the temperature through prometheus every 15seconds but i have no idea how i should do that.

thanks.